# How batch processing systems deal with a lot of objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a question in mind which I'll try to explain it as well as I can.

Batch processing frameworks such as spring batch deal with a handful amount of objects.

They should process the objects part by part so they don't encounter java heap space error.

What will these kind of frameworks or systems do with garbage they produces?

Do they call `System.gc()` sometimes or they handle it in different ways?

Comment: They leave it for the garbage collector to clean up, which generally does a very good job - unless the program references many objects it no longer needs.

Comment: Do you have specifics in what you're concerns are?  Specific use cases/scenarios that you're concerned about?

Comment: I read some notes about usage of *System.gc()* being a bad practice. I know that its usage doesn't guarantee any thing but I really don't get why it is so bad to use if it has not any harmful consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection will be done prior to throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`, so you won't run out of memory because consumption is outpacing cleanup.

The question is too broad to cover what frameworks might or might not do, but in general, it's good practice to hold references to objects for a little scope as possible. That means adopting a "stream" approach to processing - where all operations on an object occur (eg read from input stream, process, write to output) before the next object is processed.

This is in contrast to reading in all objects, processing all objects then writing all output - which requires large memory usage.